# Select child object in different collection from parent object

Tags: parent, collections

I have a rig with clothes parented under it
but i seperate rig and clothes into different collections for organization
[image]

As the image above

The problem is when I select one clothes mesh in the scene and try to find it in the heirachy using "."
it always focus on the grey one under the parent rig object, not the actual mesh in the no_sleeve collection.

When the object in the scene gets a lot (not in this case), it just hard to drag along in the outliner and find it.

How can I solve it ?? Thank you, to all of your big brain.

Comment: Blender opens the first collection with the selected item. So move the armature collection below all others.

Comment: I didn't know that ! Thank you !